# Invoke external function in event handler (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, import, event-handling, react-hooks

Is it possible to invoke an external function within an event handler?

I simply want to run an external function on click, the kicker is that I also want to pass some state as props to the external function.

Example code below:

child.js

```
 import React from 'react';

 export const SomeFunction =  (props) => {
 //some logic to invoke
 };
```

parent.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { SomeFunction} from './external';

export default function Parent = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState({
        //some state here
});

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

//IS SOMETHING LIKE THIS POSSIBLE???
SomeFunction();


};

return (
    <>
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click me</button>
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is properly pass the parent's state to the function when invoking the function

```
SomeFunction({ state });
```

and then you can do:

```
export const SomeFunction = (props) => {
  console.log(props.state);
};
```